# sum numbers in a tuple and average them not working

Tags: python

I have a db query that returns tuple as below

```
[6,6,6,5,5,5,4,4]
[10,10,10,11,11,11]
[3597590, 3597588,3597558,3597544,3597590]
```

I would like to get the average of each set. I tried to sum them using different ways for example

```
for row in cur.fetchall(
x = row[4]
print map(sum, x)
```

it throws an error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

I try to convert to int but also throws error
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

Comment: It's returning strings

Comment: try `map(sum, map(int, x))`

Comment: same valueError for int() with base 10

Comment: I think map(sum,map(int,x[1:-1])) should do it. It removes the brackets from x

Comment: Does the DB actually contain strings with `[]` around them? Why? Is it supposed to be JSON? Then you should use `json.loads()` to parse it into a Python list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you have a string representing a list of integers, in that case you can use the [ast](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ast.html) module, more precisely the [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function to transform it to an actual list and sum it

```
>>> import ast
>>> test = "[3597590, 3597588,3597558,3597544,3597590]"
>>> x=ast.literal_eval(test)
>>> x
[3597590, 3597588, 3597558, 3597544, 3597590]
>>> sum(x)
17987870
>>>
```

if what you get is a string that looks as your example, then you can use the splitlines method to get each line

```
>>> test2="""[6,6,6,5,5,5,4,4]
[10,10,10,11,11,11]
[3597590, 3597588,3597558,3597544,3597590]"""
>>> lines = test2.splitlines()
>>> lines
['[6,6,6,5,5,5,4,4]', '[10,10,10,11,11,11]', '[3597590, 3597588,3597558,3597544,3597590]']
>>> map(sum,map(ast.literal_eval,lines))
[41, 63, 17987870]
>>>
```

as mention in the comments, the [json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) module is another option

```
>>> import json
>>> test
'[3597590, 3597588,3597558,3597544,3597590]'
>>> json.loads(test)
[3597590, 3597588, 3597558, 3597544, 3597590]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Copperfield is likely the right way to do it for the problem as stated.

That said, I think you should deal with the problem upstream rather than in Python.  Use the SQL [SUM and AVERAGE functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) inside your query so that the work is done by the SQL engine.